# Why this Composite Secondary couchbase Index matches only for the first field in the creation query

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

I created a composite index for my order bucket using this query :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer ON `order` (
buyer.contact.firstName, 
buyer.contact.lastName, 
ALL DISTINCT ARRAY aoc.`value` FOR aoc IN buyer.contact.communicationChannel
WHEN aoc.`communicationChannelCode`= "EMAIL" END)
WHERE _class = "com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity"
```

When i search for the buyer.contact.firstName, the query matches with the index, but it failes for the buyer.contact.lastName.
Basically it match for the first field in the query.

Here is the result of the explain for the failing field (buyer.contact.lastName):

```
{
  "plan": {
    "#operator": "Sequence",
    "~children": [
      {
        "#operator": "PrimaryScan3",
        "index": "#primary",
        "index_projection": {
          "primary_key": true
        },
        "keyspace": "order",
        "namespace": "default",
        "using": "gsi"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Fetch",
        "keyspace": "order",
        "namespace": "default"
      },
      {
        "#operator": "Parallel",
        "~child": {
          "#operator": "Sequence",
          "~children": [
            {
              "#operator": "Filter",
              "condition": "(((((`order`.`buyer`).`contact`).`lastName`) = \"jj\") and ((`order`.`_class`) = \"com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity\"))"
            },
            {
              "#operator": "InitialProject",
              "result_terms": [
                {
                  "expr": "(((`order`.`buyer`).`contact`).`lastName`)"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "#operator": "FinalProject"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "SELECT buyer.contact.lastName FROM `order` where buyer.contact.lastName = 'jj'\nAND (`_class` = \"com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity\")"
}
```

Enterprise Edition 5.5.1 build 3511

Comment: Is other way round. When you match firstName query uses index, not for lastName

Comment: It matchs only for the first field which is buyer.contact.firstName in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Index the query predicate must have leading index key as predicate.
Couchbase bucket can have any type of documents and there is no schema. Indexer will not index when leading index key is MISSING in the document. If there is no predicate on leading Index key, query must include MISSING values also, So the index will not qualify for that query and will not be used.

In your case Add one of the following to query predicate if it is okay.

```
1) AND buyer.contact.firstName IS NOT MISSING
2) AND buyer.contact.firstName IS NOT NULL
3) AND buyer.contact.firstName IS VALUED
```

Checkout "Designing Index For Query In Couchbase N1QL" in https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-practical-guide-second-edition/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have no missing data for firstName lastName and email in com.lbk.entities.OrderEntity documents , if i switch the order, then the firest field maches with index.

Comment: Index doesn't know that. If you don't have just add the addition predicate 2 to your query and it will work